# "Несдираемый" или "нездираемый"?

Tags: выбор-слов

Приемлемо ли употребление подобного слова в литературном языке? И как правильно написать "несдираемый" или "нездираемый"?

Answer (score 1):

**Глагол содрать/сдирать,** кроме основного значения, развивает большое количество **разговорных вариантов с переносным значением**.

Формы **сдираемый, несдираемый** существуют в  языке, но это сниженный стиль, который нельзя считать литературным.

**Из словаря**

СОДРАТЬ, 1. Отделить, снять, отрывая, срывая и т.п. (что-л. прикреплённое, пришитое, надетое и т.п.). // Разг. Ссадить кожу где-л.  2. (нсв. также драть). Взять что-л. слишком дорого. С. втридорога.  // Взять, получить путём вымогательства, принуждения. С кого бы ещё с. денег. С. на бутылку, на выпивку. С. взятку. С. магарыч. 3. Разг. Списать, переписать или перерисовать что-л., выдавая за своё. С. домашнее сочинение.

Answer (score 1):

> Приемлемо ли употребление подобного слова в литературном языке?

Правомерно (в значении, восходящем к 1-2 значению "содрать"). Убедительных указаний на сниженность или хотя бы разговорность этих значений я не обнаружил. В сочетаниях типа "несдираемая наклейка" использование выглядит вполне оправданным семантически.

> И как правильно написать "несдираемый" или "нездираемый"?

"Несдираемый". Приставка тут "С", приставки "З" не бывает. Наличие отрицания "НЕ" не влияет на написание приставки.